# ShapeDrawable and TableLayout

Tags: android, tablelayout

I'm trying to put a ShapeDrawable object inside a TableLayout cell. As suggested by the documentation [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/2d-graphics.html#shape-drawable) I create a custom View `mCustomView` and then add the view to the TableLayout  by doing

```
mRow.addView(mCustomView)
mTableLayout.addView(mRow)
```

Everything works fine, no errors but the shape is not displayed at all.

The code to create my drawable is

```
icon = new ShapeDrawable(new ArcShape(0, 360));
icon.setBounds(0, 0, 20, 20);
icon.getPaint().setColor(parseColor);
```

Answer (score 1):

After some more digging and researching it turns out that the best [solution](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321627091) is to pass the `ShapeDrawable` object to an `ImageView` constructor and then add this View to the table row with something like this

```
ShapeDrawable icon = new ShapeDrawable(new ArcShape(0, 360));
icon.getPaint().setColor(parseColor);
icon.setIntrinsicHeight(30);
icon.setIntrinsicWidth(30);
ImageView iv = new ImageView(this);
iv.setImageDrawable(icon);  
mRow.addView(iv);
mTableLayout.addView(mRow)
```

This solution has also the advantage of getting rid of the custom View class.